# How to edit a textField using setState?When i press the edit button i have to make a setState with a var to get back to getContent. How can i do that?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, edit, setstate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiw03.jpg)
This is a ss of the code:

So, i have to make a setState with a variable, when the var is in the if condition it has to call get content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

- Using `onChange(String? value)` method in the TextField
- If you want to setState inside a pop up menu use a `statefulbuilder` to setState inside pop up or a dialog

In most cases you can call `setState((){});` inside the onChanged method to update state based on every character the user enters. Else you can use onEditing complete to do the same.

The best way to self debug is to hover over the class object ( in this case TextField) to see it's documentation to get an idea of how you can apply your logic.

Comment: Yes, I did try and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about that, you update the controller of the TextField rather than the TextField itself. Update the value of the controller of the textField it will auto-update the value of textField.
Please check with the TextEditingController, create an instance of TextEditingController, and pass it as a controller parameter in TextField.

Comment: I already made a TextEditingController, pass it as controller parameter in TextField. The only thing left is when i press the edit button i have to make a setState with a variable which in the build condition it wll call getContent.

Comment: You should create a bool to indicate that weather enables you to edit right now and create a widget that listen to this bool to display the corresponding widget. If you wanna edit text of the text field you would use TextEditingController; if you wanna update the Textfield based on the changed you would use onChanged those callback function; if you wanna update that TextField feature or UI you would wrapper it with other widget to control the status of the widget.